# Access Oracle schema objects from another user without using user prefix

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I have a a user that has a lot of tables against their account. Lets says UserA. I can do `SELECT * FROM TABLE` and all is fine. If I login in as a different user, UserB, but make this user a readonly connection I cannot access the table, I have to use `SELECT * FROM UserA.TABLE`

Is there a way in Oracle somewhere to allow UserB access to UserA's tables without having to put the user prefix before the table name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After logging in as UserB, run the following statement:

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = UserA;
```

After that you don't have to prefix your table names.

You can create a logon trigger that does this automatically if you don't want to run it manually.

Comment: Is there not a permission that can be setup for UserB?

Comment: Changing the current_schema is the only way I know. Using the logon trigger would be the way to make this "automatic"

Answer (score 11):

You can also do this by creating a Synonym on the table:

```
CREATE SYNONYM TABLE FOR UserA.TABLE;
```

Comment: I assume I would have to create a synonym for every table that UserA has?

Comment: @Jon Unfortunately yes although you could quickly create a script by running a query on the `ALL_TABLES` system table: `SELECT 'CREATE SYNONYM ' || TABLE_NAME || ' FOR ' || OWNER || '.' || TABLE_NAME || ';' FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'UserA';`

Comment: If you want Views as well, then try the `ALL_OBJECTS` system table instead and filter by the `OBJECT_TYPE` field.

Comment: Thanks. Should SYNONYM's only exist for tables, views and procedures? I assume you dont create them for indexes etc

Comment: Correct. See the Oracle documentation for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm You should also be aware that a synonym is only for the user that created it unless you use the `PUBLIC` keyword which makes it available for all users.

Comment: If I create the synonym logged in as UserA, UserB can still access the table though

Comment: Yes. An Oracle synonym is exactly that, a synonym. Basically just an alias.